# jQuery stopped working when I moved wordpress installation up a directory

Tags: jquery, wordpress, .htaccess

I had wordpress installed at http://twentysevenstories.com/blog/ and it was working fine, but wanted to move it up to twentysevenstories.com.

I changed the site url in the wordpress settings and copied the .htaccess file and the index.php to the main directory and the site loads fine except that the jquery stopped working. It was working fine before when everything was in the subdirectory.

Would it be better to just move the entire wordpress installation up to the root directory?

Comment: there must be something wrong with the paths

Comment: Try opening firebug. Does the used jquery path have `/blog/` within?

Comment: All the paths seem to be fine. They point to the location where the jquery is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are going to move the installation move all files. There are likely relative path references that rely on the directory structure. Of course, you should always back up EVERYTHING before experimenting with any changes like this, just in case.

But, I have moved Wordpress installations like this before and as long as the parent directory was not being used by some other installation it all worked fine. Related documentation:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: I've followed all the steps on that page for Moving on Your Existing Server. I also moved all the files to the root directory, but I'm still not having luck with the jQuery loading. Is there a way I can debug to see if something isn't loading. `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
$.ready.$.localScroll.defaults.axisscripts.js
o.extend.ready.o.readyListjquery.min.js
o.extend.eachjquery.min.js
o.extend.readyjquery.min.js
o.each.o.fn.(anonymous function)` is what I get from firebug

Answer (score 0):

In FireBug I kept getting the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function`

I figured out that there was a conflict with the jQuery libraries.

By adding `jQuery.noConflict()` and changing te global variable `$` to `jQuery` it resolved the error.

Two links that were useful:

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Overriding_the_.24-function

http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/